# How to establish SSL/TLS socket connection with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, certificate

I've created a very simple socket server with NodeJS (v8.11.3) and it's working fine. My goal is to keep a socket connection opened with an electronic device (IoT).

**QUESTION**: How to make communication secure, that is, how to make socket/SSL socket communication? NOTE: I have also created a self-signed certificate for testing.

The test socket server (without security) is the one below. I have no experience with NodeJS, so I think there are a lot better ways to establish a socket connection...

```
const net = require('net')

net.createServer(socket => {
    socket.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Socket Error: ')
        console.log(err.stack)
    })

    socket.on('data', function(data){
        msg = ''
        msg = data.toString();
        socket.write(msg)
        console.log(msg)
    })
}).listen(8001)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in [`tls` module](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html), which provides extensions of `net.Server` and `net.Socket`. As such, it works about the same as the `net` server creation, with more options and more events. There is a simple example in the [`tls.createServer` section](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener), which shows a basic server close to your code here.

Comment: I followed the example documentation and managed to connect my device, but the connections are unauthorized. On the side of my device, only the Fingerprint is sent to the server. After connecting to the server I can even see the "hello world!" sent by the device, that is, the server accepts the connection and shows the data in `socket.pipe (socket)`, but the connection is classified as unauthorized. What is missing?

Comment: On the side of my device I can also see the "welcome!" from the server.

Comment: Maybe you didn't set certificates properly on the device's side? Check the example in [this section](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback), other than that, I have no idea.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't identify the problem, but curiously the data is sent from the device to the server and also back to the device. The certificate is validated, the fingerprint is recognized (because if I swap any information the client-server connection will fail) so I don't understand ... but it seems to be working fine. I've to think more about it. Thank you.